# ActionSheet is resetting my button layout on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiactionsheet, uipangesturerecognizer

I have created an app which lets you move an image around on someones face. The image is a button handled by the following gestures:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
}

- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
    CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
    CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;
    NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

    float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
    finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width);
    finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
    } completion:nil];

}

}
```

The problem is that when I load an action sheet using:

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Save to camera roll" otherButtonTitles:@"Email as attachment", @"Share on Facebook", @"Post to Twitter", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
[popupQuery release];
}
```

The button (image) either resets to the original place when the view was loaded or jumps around the screen to a random place. I am taking a screenshot of the complete image and saving this in order to share it so this messes up the final image.

I believe I may need to set the co-ordinates where the button is perhaps or maybe I am going about the solution the wrong way.

Any help greatly appreciated.